# How to remove back button action while page is loading

Tags: iphone

In my project i have a list when select on a item it will take to next controller using PushViewController. When i go there i will get data using libxml parser. But when i am clicking on the back button while loading it is showing exception. So i want to disable back button action till loading of data is completed how can i handle it.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view controller:

```
[[self navigationItem] setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

This is documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006933-CH3-SW4).